# node server and keeping remote connections alive

Tags: node.js, soap, connection

I have a node server that needs to communicate with a single remote SOAP server. I establish this connection and reuse it throughout the run. 
Except this server is not very reliable and crashes some time :(

So at some point during the run, I make a call and I get socket connection error. 
What is a standard customary, pattern, to deal with this issue. To ensure the integrity of a remote connection?

Adding existing code, so the idea, is once the connection to the SOAP server is established, we will just use it...

```
   var SoapClient = function() {
    var soap = require('soap');


    this.init = function (){
        var url = "http://172.31.19.39/my.wsdl";
        var endPoint = "https://172.31.19.39:8342";
        var options = {};
        options.endpoint = endPoint;


        soap.createClient(url, options, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('soap client create failed ' + err);
                return;

            }
            console.log('init is called ready');
            SoapClient.instance = result;
            SoapClient.instance.setSecurity(new soap.BasicAuthSecurity(
                    'admin-priv', 'password'));
        });
    };
};

SoapClient.getInstance  = function () {

    if (SoapClient.instance) {
        return SoapClient.instance;
    }

    new SoapClient().init();

    return SoapClient.instance;
};

SoapClient.instance = null;

//module.exports = SoapClient;
exports.getInstance = SoapClient.getInstance;
```

Comment: This really depends on your setup. Share some code of what you've tried already so its easier to see the direction you took.

Comment: @jibsales Just updated the original post

Comment: There's no way to "ensure the integrity of a remote connection." It's up to the API to ensure that and for both the client and server to have a method for handling robustness. The best you can do is to handle errors and retry requests as needed.